# Accessing Facebook wall posts

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql, facebook-wall

Is there a way, via FQL or the Facebook API, to access the wall posts to a fan page (not a profile)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Stream.get with the source id set to the page id of a fan page. I tried this on the developer console using the cocacola fan page (id 40796308305) and I think it accomplishes what you are trying to achieve.

This is the php example that the dev console gives me:

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_get('',40796308305,'0','0',30,'','','','');
```

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get

Comment: I get "stream requires the read_stream extended permission." when running this in the dev console. What's the trick to this?

Comment: That probably means you do not have proper permission to view the fan page, I used my viewer_id to view the fan page that the member was part of, and i had read_stream and extended permission for the viewer_id